# How do you ask to know whether "reaching" a doctor's service was easily accessible?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to write down a questionnaire for people (patients) on vacation, who were served by a doctor/nurse on the scene (in this example, at the hotel). I would like to ask whether the service provided by doctor/nurse was easily accessible. But it sounds a little erratic to ask as "Were you able to **reach** the doctor/nurse at the hotel easily?"
Any alternative which would sound more formal?

Comment: Your sentence looks fine. It might be a tiny bit clearer if you say, "*... able to **contact***". Also, it's better to use "*...doctor **or** nurse...*" rather than using the /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence looks fine. It might be a tiny bit clearer if you say, "... able to contact". Also, it's better to use "...doctor or nurse..." rather than using the / –
gotube
♦

Comment: Comment converted to answer